# Populating Two Dropdownlist on PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have two Dropdownlist in my one webpage. The second one relies on first one to load.
For instance, if first one is "Melbourne", second one list all the suburbs of melbourne.

Code is perfectly working but when i first load the page, the second dropdownlist2 doesn't populate.
I need to select "Melbourne" again to populate second Dropdownlist.

Here is my code for Page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["Username"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
        }

        if (getAccess(Session["Username"].ToString()) == false)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Unauthorized.aspx");
        }

        DataSet ds = GetAllCategory();
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "identifier";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "OS_ID"; //Change field to one you want.
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Selected Index Changed code

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = softwareType(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "identifier";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ST_ID"; //Change field to one you want.
        DropDownList2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to fix this simple issue?

Comment: Have you set Autopostback=true in 1st dropdown???

Comment: on which event you want your second dropdown to populate???

Comment: You should bind data for DropDownList2 when first time load the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    DataSet ds = GetAllCategory();
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "identifier";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "OS_ID"; //Change field to one you want.
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }

   if(DropDownList1.Items.Count > 0)
   { 
       DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
       DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(this,null);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea could be get the first value from the `GetAllCategory`
The bind the second `dropdown list` on page load.

```
public void PopulateDropdownList2(int selectedValue)
{
    DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
    DataSet ds = softwareType(selectedValue);
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
           DropDownList2.DataTextField = "identifier";
           DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ST_ID"; //Change field to one you want.
           DropDownList2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
           DropDownList2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

call the above function on

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{

}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["Username"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
        }

        if (getAccess(Session["Username"].ToString()) == false)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Unauthorized.aspx");
        }

        DataSet ds = GetAllCategory();
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "identifier";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "OS_ID"; //Change field to one you want.
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            PopulateDropdownList2(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["identifier"].ToString()));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How can i select first item of the dropdownlist by code so that the second one populates on Page Load

Answer (score 0):

Update with your markup , have you set `Autopost="true"` or alternatively you can use [Ajaxtoolkit's cascading dropdowns](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/cascadingdropdown/cascadingdropdown.aspx)

Comment: or after databind in first dropdown you can call `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);`

Answer (score 0):

try adding this line below DropDownList1.DataBind();

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

call this on page load if(!ispostback) as well as select index change of first ddl

```
private void fillSecondDdl()
{
DataSet ds = softwareType(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "identifier";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ST_ID"; //Change field to one you want.
        DropDownList2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call this function in pageload in the end

```
fillSecondDropdown(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));



 public void  fillSecondDropdown(int firstdropdownValue)
    {
    DataSet ds = softwareType(firstdropdownValue);
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "identifier";
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ST_ID"; //Change field to one you want.
            DropDownList2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor the function out of DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged() and put it into a new function:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ddl1Changed(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}

public void ddl1Changed(string selectedValue)
{
    DataSet ds = softwareType(Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue));
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "identifier";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ST_ID"; //Change field to one you want.
        DropDownList2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

then

on your Page_Load:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["Username"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
        }

        if (getAccess(Session["Username"].ToString()) == false)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Unauthorized.aspx");
        }

        DataSet ds = GetAllCategory();
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "identifier";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "OS_ID"; //Change field to one you want.
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }

        ddl1Changed("Melbourne");
    }


}
```